# Create a link on click and open that link in Iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, url, iframe

Here, I am trying to create a link using different IP.P1 will be f=one IP, P2 will be the host and then on click, it should create a link and then open it in the Iframe.
Please tell me where I am going wrong?? SRC in iframe not taking the link

```
    <body> 
       p1: <input type="text" id="p1" value="fvalue" >
       P2: <input type="text" id="p2" value="svalue">

       <p>Click On button.</p>

       <button id="p3" onclick =openlink()>link</button>
       <iframe id= "iframe1" src = link , width = 300px hight = 200px></iframe>
       <script>
          function openlink () {
          var a = document.getElementById("p1").value ;
          var b = document.getElementById("p2").value ;

          link = ( a + ":"+ b + "/webhdfs/v1/?user.name=hduser1&op=LISTSTATUS" ).value;
         }
       </script>



        </script>
</body>

</html>
```

My link keep on changing so I can't put direct link as SRC.

Comment: Instead of that `link` line you need `iframe1.src = a + ":" + b + "/webhdfs/v1/?user.name=hduser1&op=LISTSTATUS";` (Regardless of the String.value you have there for some reason, `src=link` won't work like that; even if it did magically take on the value of the variable in the future; it actually sets the `src` to the literal text `"link"`)

Comment: okay but then what should I put in src in <iframe>??if i just put "" it is giving error of undefined

Comment: The `:` suggests this is a URL containing username and password? In this case you probably need this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/grcs21m7/

Comment: i checked it ,It is still not getting.

Comment: Ok, so maybe next time specify example values of what a and b are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the function `openlink`,

do 
`var iFrame = document.getElementById("iframe1")`

`iFrame.setAttribute("src",a + ":"+ b + "/webhdfs/v1/?user.name=hduser1&op=LISTSTATUS")`

it should look something like this

```
      function openlink () {
      var iFrame = document.getElementById("iframe1")
      var a = document.getElementById("p1").value ;
      var b = document.getElementById("p2").value ;

      iFrame.setAttribute("src",a + ":"+ b + "/webhdfs/v1/?user.name=hduser1&op=LISTSTATUS")
     }
```

on a side note, es6 template strings look a lot cleaner